# why does vscode not suggest closing tags?

Tags: visual-studio-code

i have vscode. it sometimes auto-completes tags in html files by suggesting what the tag is that I have open, such as this p tag.

[image]

and other times i have no idea why it suggests half of what is in the list and doesn't want to close the tag at all. it is particularly bad with web components.

[image]

vscode used to be really great at this, and more recently it has become abysmally bad at tags and auto-suggestions.

how can i just get the build in 'whatever-built-in-plugin-is-doing-this-badly' to cooperate and at least suggest closing the current tag?

```
Version: 1.77.0
Commit: 7f329fe6c66b0f86ae1574c2911b681ad5a45d63
Date: 2023-03-29T09:55:48.214Z
Electron: 19.1.11
Chromium: 102.0.5005.196
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.26-electron.0
OS: Darwin arm64 21.6.0
Sandboxed: No
```

Comment: Please try to install extensions like ```Auto Close Tag```
[enter image description here][1]

it may fix your problem. Or choose the correct **Intellisense** on what your language you are using.


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/26lav.png

Comment: when you took your second screenshot, what was the editor's language mode? (see the bottom right corner of the screen). was it HTML? JSX? something else?

Comment: have you set `html.autoClosingTags` to `false`? I'm confused about how to even reproduce what you are seeing. some more thorough procedure than just screenshots would help.

Answer (score 1):

Try typing the name of a tag, without starting with the `<` character, this should make some hints appear. You can then navigate through the list with the arrow keys, and if you press `Enter`, a pair of tags (opening + closing) will be created, based on what hint you highlighted. There is no extension that enables this, it's just a built-in VSC feature.

Even more shortcuts (they're called Emmet Abbreviations, by the way):

If the tag you're creating should have a `class` attribute, type the name of the tag like before, followed by a `.`, then hit `Enter`. For tags with an `id` attribute, you would put `#` instead. Also, you can type an id after the `#` or a class name after the `.`, just do **not** hit the spacebar or the popup hints will disappear.

As an example:

Typing `div.foo` then hitting `Enter` will result in:

```
<div class="foo"></div>
```

You can even combine the dot and hash techniques!
If you write `span.foo#bar`, then hit `Enter`, VSC will transform this into:

```
<span class="foo" id="bar"></span>
```

Comment: while this is useful info in general, I'm not sure if it has strong relevance to this question, which seems to be about getting suggestions for closing tags once opening tags have been typed without accepting suggestions for the tag pair when typing the opening tag. actually, this shouldn't even be necessary. auto-closing tags should happen automatically, and this doesn't answer why it doesn't.